# Would a comma go before an introductory phrase when a word such as "yesterday" goes before it?

Tags: phrases, commas, clauses

I'm really confused about adding a comma before an introductory phrase. Here's my original sentence:

> "*Yesterday I found Susan's missing cat.*"

I wanted to add the introductory phrase, "*While I was getting the mail,*" after "*yesterday*," but I didn't know if the sentence should be written like this,

> "*Yesterday while I was getting the mail, I found Susan's missing cat.*"

Or,

> "*Yesterday, while I was getting the mail, I found Susan's missing cat.*"

Is a comma required after "*yesterday*" when an introductory phrase, such as "*While I was getting the mail,*" or is it preference, just like how it's preference to have a comma after words such as "*today*," "*yesterday*," "*now*"?

Comment: Or you could write *Yesterday—while I was getting the mail—I found Susan's missing cat.* with no commas at all.

Comment: Or you could write _I found Susan's missing cat yesterday while I was getting the mail_ with no punctuation at all :-)

Answer (score 3):

All punctuation is a matter of style (and thus preference). There are some rules agreed-upon by style manuals, and two are in play here:

1. Place a comma after an introductory adverbial clause of suitable length.
2. Precede non-restrictive elements with a comma; omit the comma for restrictive elements.

Thus, if you mean that you found the cat yesterday, and oh, by the way you happened to be getting the mail, then write

> Yesterday, while I was getting the mail, I found Susan's missing cat.

Your getting the mail is an aside, merely additional and less important information, and thus it's nonrestrictive, and the comma goes before *while*.

If, on the other hand, you mean that you found the cat yesterday while you were getting the mail as opposed to yesterday say, while you were weeding the garden, then write

> Yesterday while I was getting the mail, I found Susan's missing cat.

Now, you found the cat at a particular time yesterday, making the the mail retrieval definitional (i.e., restrictive) and no comma goes before *while*.

Notice in both cases, a comma follows *mail* to set off the introductory clause from the rest of the sentence.

Comment: Would you say the same to setting off "hopefully" with commas in a sentence like this: "I want to go to college and hopefully get good grades"?

Comment: @Tim *Hopefully* is just verbal static. It certainly doesn't mean that you want to obtain your grades in a hopeful manner. It's sort of a substitute for "... and I hope to get good grades." So I'm reluctant to treat it as an adverb like *effortlessly* (which wouldn't take a comma) or as an aside like *as I'm expecting* (which would). In my view, punctuation should aid your readers in parsing your sentences (and in particular help them avoid erroneous parsing). A comma or its absence after *hopefully* neither helps nor hurts, so it's up to you as a matter of style.